# Where can I find the source for springloaded-core jar?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-loaded

I can't seem to find this anywhere and am assuming that this jar is built as part of something else. Anyone know where I can get the source? I am using version 1.0.2.

Comment: Interesting. It's mentioned a few places but springsource and grails don't seem to have the source anywhere public. If you just want one or two classes you could try decompiling them with Jad or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it on GitHub here....

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-loaded